# adding image to called function from another class in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have started working with swift recently. I have a function to resize the image in one swift file and I wanted to call it in another swift file. Here is the function which was added in class UIImage:

```
public extension UIImage{
class func scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let uimageview = UIImage()
        let widthRatio = targetSize.width / uimageview.size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / uimageview.size.height
        
        let scaleFactor = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        
        let scaledImageSize = CGSize(
            width: uimageview.size.width * scaleFactor,
            height: uimageview.size.height * scaleFactor
        )

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(
            size: scaledImageSize
        )

        let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
            uimageview.draw(in: CGRect(
                origin: .zero,
                size: scaledImageSize
            ))
        }
        
        return scaledImage
    }
}
```

so when I want to call this function in another file to resize "myimage", I think I should write like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myimage")
let targetSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
let scaledImage = image.UIImage.scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: targetSize)
```

but by adding 'image' before UIImage.scalePreservingAspectRatio(), it does not recognize the function and it shows an error: Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'UIImage'. So I don't know how I can use my image for this function in another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call it on UIImage, it needs to be put into an extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    func scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        ...
    }
}
```

You also probably want it to be able to access the image that you call it on, so remove `class` from the function declaration. Then you can call it like:

```
image.scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: size)
```

Then update the code to use `self` instead of creating a new source image:

```
func scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let widthRatio = targetSize.width / size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height

    let scaleFactor = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)

    let scaledImageSize = CGSize(
        width: size.width * scaleFactor,
        height: size.height * scaleFactor
    )

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(
        size: scaledImageSize
    )

    let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
        self.draw(in: CGRect(
            origin: .zero,
            size: scaledImageSize
        ))
    }

    return scaledImage
}
```

Comment: It is into an extension, I just forgot to mention it. I edited my code and added the extension to my question, to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.